# Measure RTT of WebsocketServer: Single Message or bulk of messages?

Tags: performance, websocket, network-protocols, measurement, roundtrip

I recently changed something in the WebsocketServer implementation of one of my projects, that (presumably) decreases the Round-Trip-Time (RTT) of its messages. I want to measure the RTT of both implementations to compare them. For this, I am sending `m` messages of `s` bytes from `c` different connections.

The thing I am wondering now is: Should the RTT be measured for each message separately - remembering the sending time of each message and when the response arrives -, or should I remember the time the **first** message was sent and the response to the **last** message arrives? Which one is more accurate?

I would probably go for the first approach, what made me wondering is that [websocket-benchmark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-benchmark) seems to use the latter approach. Is this just an oversight or is there a reasoning behind it?